# Windows Authentication is greyed out when creating a new ASP.NET 5 Web Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a new ASP.NET 5 Web Application and windows authentication is greyed out in Visual Studio 2015. It is not greyed out for ASP.NET 4.7 or 4.5 templates.

Is there something I need to do to fix this, is there any detriment to not choosing this when I want to make an intranet application? I cannot select anything other than Cloud authentication types for "Work And School Accounts".

Comment: Gotcha, thanks mason. I'm new to ASP.NET and only have the ability to host it on a Linux server for work. I'd love to utilize DNX over Mono, which affected my decision to try and use ASP.NET 5.

Comment: That just sounds like a disaster waiting to happen until the system has stabilized.

Comment: Thanks for the honest feedback. All good stuff to know, I'll work with 4.6 instead till 5 is complete.